# bowser.execute logging and finding about?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have this code where the developer is trying to test the value:

```
expect(browser.executeScript('return !!obj.isCustomer();')).toBe(myCurrentVal);
```

I am trying to find out what `!!` means in `!!obj.isCustomer()` and also how can I get it's value? Can I add console.log somewhere in `browser.executeScript` without just getting some nonsense logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!!` is the simplest way of taking a value and converting it to a Boolean.  The developer is checking to see if `obj.customer()` returns a truthy or falsey value (and expecting it to be equal to `myCurrentVal`.

If you want to see the result of `!!obj.isCustomer()` in action, I suggest you load the actual page in a browser (not with Protractor) and run it in the console.  Protractor is for end-to-end testing and not typical debugging.  You can't add a `console.log` to the `executeScript` call because it will be run in the browser context (and not Protractors)